# Need help to understand this code to find the position of 1's in a given number

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

The following code helps us in finding position of the one bits in a given number:

```
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for (int d = 30; d >= 0; d--){
        if (n << ~d < 0){
            System.out.print(d + " ");
        }
    }
```

For example: If n = 5, its binary representation is 101 and the 1s are at the 0th and 2nd positions, so the output will be `2 0`.

Some more examples:

```
n        Output
8        3
149      7 4 2 0
```

I am unable to understand the meaning of this code:

```
n << ~d < 0.
```

I know the concept of right shift and compliment but want to know how this specific expression evaluates to a negative number when `n` has a bit set at position `d`.

Comment: Do you not understand what `n << ~d < 0` does or why it gives the positions of the 1s?

Comment: Read up on [Bitwise and Bit Shift](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: yes this part @tobias_k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is trickier than it looks and looks like it's designed to use bitwise operations in places where simpler arithmetic operations might be a bit clearer.

Because integers in Java are represented in the signed two's-complement representation, taking the bitwise complement of a number is equivalent to negating it and adding one. Restated mathematically:

> ~x = -x + 1

This means that the code

```
n << ~d
```

is equivalent to

```
n << (-d + 1).
```

Now that's weird, because that would mean that you're left-shifting by a negative amount... which doesn't make much sense. This is where we need to go to the [Java Language Specification on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19), which says the following about a left-shift:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

In other words, the shift operation completely ignores everything except the bottom five bits of the numeric value. This means that we're not actually shifting by a negative amount - we're shifting by a *positive* amount, and the specific amount depends on the lowest five bits of the quantity `~d`. (I'm switching back to using complement rather than negative values, since at this point it seems like the arithmetic interpretation of `~d` might not be all that useful.)

If we take the number `d`, flip all the bits, then just focus on the lowest five bits, it ends up being equivalent to evaluating 31 - d. To see this, notice that 31 has binary representation 11111, so if we start with 11111 and subtract out the number d, then every 1 bit gets flipped to a 0 (1 - 1 = 0) and every zero bit gets flipped to a 1 (1 - 0 = 1). In other words, the expression

```
n << ~d
```

is completely equivalent - in this context - to

```
n << (31 - d)
```

because d is always between 0 and 31.

This now gives us more of a clue what's going on here. Remember that in a signed 32-bit representation of an integer, the very first bit of the integer is the sign bit. If it's 1, the value is negative, and if it's 0, the value is nonnegative. So if we take n and shift it forward 31 - d positions, then we're pushing the dth bit of the number into the very first bit position (play around with this a bit if it's not clear why). If the dth bit is a 1, then this sets the sign bit and makes the number negative, and if the dth bit is a 0 this sets the sign bit to zero and makes the number nonnegative. This is why

```
(n << ~d) < 0
```

tests whether the bit is set - it's checking whether the 1 bit in the original position triggers the sign bit in the resultant number.

Having said all this, I feel like this is way more complex than it needs to be. It's probably clearer to test the bit directly by masking off everything else and seeing if anything's left:

```
if ((n & (1 << d)) != 0)
```

which is (probably) a bit easier to read.

Comment: Awesome explanation @templatelypedef. Thanks.